# Add pages content to startpage through custom menu

Tags: menus, pages, navigation

I would like to be able to add page content onto the startpage (index.php). But only the pages that i've added in custom menu, and in that order too.

I've been searching for a while now, but can't find anything close.

Big thanks to any one that can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_nav_menu_locations` and `wp_get_nav_menu_items` to get your menu items.

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$nav_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($locations['your-menu-slug']);
```

You can then process `$nav_items` to display your page content. It can get complicated but it does work.